# Views: creating a hierarchy of content - am I doing it right?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, nodes

This is a little complicated, but here goes:

- I have a taxonomy vocabulary in a tree-structure.
- I have a content type with a field of the vocabulary.
- I am using the [Views Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) module to display a tree of the vocabulary, and want the content to display within the tree. (Please see the illustration below).
- In my view I use a relationship to add the links to the content type to the view.
- animal

  - mammal

    - [DOG](http://www.example.com/)
    - [CAT](http://www.example.com/)
- vegetable

  - flowering plant

    - [ROSE](http://www.example.com/)

This would seem to me to be a fairly common thing to do. Am I doing it right? (i.e. is creating a taxonomy vocabulary and using Views Tree the best way to do this?)

Comment: One thing I'm having a real issue with is repeating elements in the view, i.e. I can't create the example view above without "mammal" appearing above "CAT". I have tried fixing this issue with the [Views distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module but that removes the CAT row completely (because it is contained within the repeated elements).

Comment: You should probably say what you actually want to achieve – otherwis it's difficult to tell if you're doing it *right*. If for example you simply want to order a lot of content in a hierachical way, then your approach appears to be the *right* way.

Comment: Well, it is for a hierarchical directory of content items. I still haven't solved the issue of repeating headings in the view, but I'm working on it (now trying the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module).

Answer (score 1):

A taxonomy tree is often the first that comes to mind thinking of a hierarchical directory of content items – but similar structures can also be built in many different ways. Here's just two examples that I personally find often easier to handle, than a taxonomy tree:

- [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/Entityreference) – rather than having 'lists' of content items 'attached' to taxonomy terms, to me this approach has a more 'real' feel concerning the item-to-item relations. You actually have nodes (items) that can either be partens, children or siblings of nodes (or content types) with all the advatages that come with nodes like commenting etc. And the free tagging reference field let's you even generate new elements 'remotely'.
- [Book module](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/book) – probably one of the most underrated core modules – let's you genrate complex tree structures out of the box. While I consider it ideal for a quick start, it might become a bit low-fi in the long run.

For me reading this article "[RIP Taxonomy Module in Drupal 7](http://www.digett.com/blog/04/04/2012/rip-taxonomy-module-drupal-7)" was appeared to be quite helpful when I (again) had to decide how to build a tree of related nodes.

Comment: I read that "RIP" article, but I'm not sure I agree. Entity reference is great for linking content types, but if what you want actually _is_ a hierarchical taxonomy, (with for instance multiple branches, some of which only have content at the tips) then it seems taxonomy is a better solution.

Comment: okay, i see… Just for the record: you can (of course) also have multiple branches with either of the two suggested alternatives. To me 'entity reference' actually appears to be more flexible than taxo-trees – but maybe that's just personal prefs.

Comment: How do you have empty branches just using Entity references? A taxonomy is just an empty tree which can be populated with content, but with entity references you have to reference content, don't you? Or am I missing something?

Comment: To have 'empty branches' you could of course just leave pages empty or even have a content type that only consists of a title. However – if you already know your taxonomy and you want to prepare all branches so that for example an editor can then just 'fill' them – and you feel comfortable with taxonomy trees – then you should probably go that way. I just wanted to point out that there are quite some alternative approaches possible.